# lucene 3.0.3 | searching problem with *.docx file

Tags: lucene.net, zend-search-lucene, lucene

I am creating index with help of **StandardAnalyzer** for ***.docx** file it's fine. But at the time of searching it do not gives result for these *.docx file.

any help or suggestion will be appreciated!!!

Comment: What do you exactly need? To index the .docx's body?

Answer (score 0):

How do you convert the *.docx file to an indexable (text) format?

We use Apache POI to get our *.docx (and other office formats) indexed and this works pretty fine!

You can have a look at the Implementation here: http://code.google.com/p/gtxcontentconnector/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcontentconnector-poi-transformer%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgentics%2Fcr%2Flucene%2Findexer%2Ftransformer